# Completed order reverting to processing

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

A portion of my completed orders revert to processing on seemingly random days.

Most recently, according to "Updated at" on the orders, this occurred on Feb. 26th 2:30:00PM give or take a few seconds. Can I see which crons ran on this day around this time?

Below are some extra details that I hope will help you understand the modules that I know manipulate my order statuses.

## Order Process Details:

1. Custom Order Statuses
   [image: Custom Order Status]
2. Order Submitted
3. Using Authorize Direct Post method, if payment authorized the order status is set to **Payment Authorized**.
4. Using XTENTO Sales Export Module

   - if status = "Payment Authorized" export to Navision
   - Set status to "Processing in Navision"
5. Using XTENTO Tracking Number Import

   - If order invoiced and shipped completely set order status to = Complete.

Once the mishap occurs, the order status becomes "Processing". In my setup a status of "Processing" is never set.

Comment: They're revering to 'processing` state, got it. But what is the status? `payment_authorized` or `sent_to_navision`?

Comment: @musicliftsme , i've clarified what the status is set to in my original post. Once everything above has taken place sometime later the order is set to "Processing". Nowhere in my process is the status ever meant to be set to "Processing"

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the order status/state code `Processing`/`processing` is your "Default Status" under System > Order Statuses. This is the status/state code that Magento will automatically set to an order when there is an update on the order that doesn't change the state of it. I don't know the exact details, but it's something like that.

For example, the `Processing in Navision`/`processing` order may get something done on it in the admin or in a process to update it somehow without changing its state code. Magento will update your order to the "Default Status", resulting your `Processing in Navision` order to become `Processing`.

You can test this by opening up a `Processing in Navision` order and adding an invoice or shipment to it. It will change to `Processing`.

If this is happening, you'll either need to set a different "Default Status" for state code `processing`. Or you'll need to hook onto an event to check the status and correct it every time your order is saved. The former is much more elegant. The latter can get really messy, from what I've experienced.

Unfortunately, since this sort of issue requires digging into the code, this is all I got.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that this helps me troubleshoot the source of the problem. I could assume, based on this, that Tracking Number Import is attempting to create an invoice and not setting a status - but it does not touch already completed orders and all orders that are impacted by this were completed at one point.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where state code `complete` orders are being reverted. You obviously have customization. At this point, I can only tell you that you should begin searching for strings like `$order-save()`, `$order->setState(`, etc. to get an idea what parts are modifying your orders.